# Google Maps API v3 MapTypeId as variable

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

When setting the google map type:

```
map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN);
```

Can I replace "TERRAIN" by a js variable containing the string "TERRAIN", "SATELLITE", etc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, call it like this:

```
var mapType = "TERRAIN";
map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId[mapType]);
```

Comment: Appreciate this @Mathletics

Answer (score -1):

```
//Console output of MapTypeId
google.maps.MapTypeId
{ROADMAP: "roadmap", SATELLITE: "satellite", HYBRID: "hybrid", TERRAIN:"terrain"}
HYBRID:"hybrid"
ROADMAP:"roadmap"
SATELLITE:"satellite"
TERRAIN:"terrain"


//change mapTypeId
map.setMapTypeId("terrain"); //example with hybrid
//or
map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN); // same example with hybrid
//or as you want
map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId["TERRAIN"]); // same example with hybrid
```

Comment: This does **not** provide an answer to the original question, which, btw. has already been answered with the appropriate solution.